# accepts_nested_attributes_for alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

In `Topic` model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :choices, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices
  attr_accessible :title, :choices
end
```

During a POST create, the `params` submitted is `:choices`, instead of `:choices_attributes` expected by Rails, and giving an error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Choice(#70365943501680) expected,
got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70365951899600)):
```

Is there a way to config `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to accept params passing as `choices` instead of `choices_attributes` in a JSON call?

Currently, I did the attributes creation in the controller (which seems not to be an elegant solution):

```
  def create
    choices = params[:topic].delete(:choices)
    @topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
    if choices
      choices.each do |choice|
        @topic.choices.build(choice)
      end
    end
    if @topic.save
      render json: @topic, status: :created, location: @topic
    else
      render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but I just ran into the same problem.  Is there any other way around this?  It looks like that "_attributes" string is hardcoded in the nested_attributes.rb code (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L337).

Assigning "choices_attributes" to a property when submitting a form is fine, but what if it's being used for an API.  In that case it just doesn't make sense.

Does anyone have a way around this or an alternative when passing JSON for an API?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Well, since I haven't heard any updates on this I'm going to show how I'm getting around this right now.  Being new to Rails, I'm open to suggestions, but this is the only way I can figure it out at the moment.

I created an adjust_for_nested_attributes method in my API base_controller.rb

```
def adjust_for_nested_attributes(attrs)     
  Array(attrs).each do |param|
    if params[param].present? 
      params["#{param}_attributes"] = params[param]
      params.delete(param)
    end
  end
end
```

This method basically converts any attributes that are passed in to #{attr}_attributes so that it works with accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Then in each controller that needs this functionality I added a before_action like so

```
before_action only: [:create] do 
  adjust_for_nested_attributes(:choices) 
end
```

Right now I'm only worried about creation, but if you needed it for update you could add that into the 'only' clause of the before_action.

Answer (score 0):

You can create method `choices=` in model as

```
def choices=(params)
  self.choices_attributes = params
end
```

But you'll break your setter for choices association.

The best way is to modify your form to return `choices_attributes` instead `choices`

Answer (score 0):

```
  # Adds support for creating choices associations via `choices=value`
  # This is in addition to `choices_attributes=value` method provided by
  # `accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices`
  def choices=(value)
    value.is_a?(Array) && value.first.is_a?(Hash) ? (self.choices_attributes = value) : super
  end
```